# Java, how to put 2 JPanels next to each other

Tags: java, swing

I want to put 2 JPanels next to each other in 1 JFrame. My JFrame is 1200 in width.

But I want the left panel to have the size of 300 and my right panel be the size of 900.

Comment: You should be able to set the preferred sizes of the `JPanel` accordingly, then put them both in a `BoxLayout`. If you can't get taht to work, then please show us a [mcve] of what you're tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `JFrame` with `BorderLayout` and then set the first `JPanel` orientation `West` and the other set to `Center`. The first `JPanel` set 300 width. The other panel will be with the adjusted to the Frame

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for